# Limiting caption to width of the image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I wrap the text in a `figcaption` when it reaches the right side of an image?

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.flex-figure-item {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
}
figcaption {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <figure class="flex-figure-item">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x200" alt="placeholder">
    <figcaption>Short, John</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="flex-figure-item">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x200" alt="placeholder">
    <figcaption>WrapMe, Longname should not go past right side of image</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="flex-figure-item">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x200" alt="placeholder">
    <figcaption>Short, Sally</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Here is the pen: http://codepen.io/mjankowski/pen/pbzejy

In the case above, the second figure caption moves well beyond the right hand side of the image. I would want it to wrap after "Longname".

Also, open to suggestions for a simpler approach. I just want the images/captions to be neat and tidy.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Michael, Thank you for the edits! Adding the css really made the question much more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method would be to make your `figure` elements flex containers, and set their alignment to `flex-direction: column`. This would give you more control over the width of the entire element.

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.flex-figure-item {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
      
  display: flex;           /* NEW */
  flex-direction: column;  /* NEW */
  width: 150px;            /* NEW */
}
figcaption {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <figure class="flex-figure-item">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x200" alt="placeholder">
    <figcaption>Short, John</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="flex-figure-item">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x200" alt="placeholder">
    <figcaption>WrapMe, Longname should not go past right side of image</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="flex-figure-item">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x200" alt="placeholder">
    <figcaption>Short, Sally</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOzeLe)

Comment: This worked very well. Thank you! I did add some space to separate out the lines. padding-top: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;

Comment: I was having the same problem as the OP and this is the best of the solutions I found. Thank you!