# Shrinkwrap image container with caption

Tags: html, css, image

I'm having some trouble adding a caption to a shrink wrapped div whose width is being provided by an image.

The thing is, I want the width of the image to be set by a user through PHP which in turn will affect the width of the parent div.

```
<div class="shrinkwrap">
   <img src="image.jpg" width="$width">
</div>

.shrinkwrap {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

This useful trick has served me well, but when I want to add a caption to the image, and said caption exceeds the width of the image, it pushes the width of the parent div.

I've tried different approaches with this caption (positioning, flexbox, etc) but since the shrinkwrap container will take the width of it's children, if the caption is the widest, it will affect the overall look of this.

Setting the width of the container div and giving the image 100% width is a quick solution but to make it dynamic I had to use inline styles which isn't nice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="shrinkwrap">
<img id="version1" src="http://placehold.it/520x320" width="320px" alt="" />

  <div class="caption">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit ius ex admodum consequuntur, te dicunt epicurei invenire eum, te ius vocent eligendi. Sed unum persecuti te, tempor nostrud disputationi eos ad. ius ex admodum consequuntur, te dicunt epicurei inv!
  </div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.shrinkwrap { 
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
}

#version1 {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.caption {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nx39rkev/49/

Comment: Why not duplicate the php width on the caption, as well? Or on the container?

Comment: If you are able to limit the container width to the dynamic image width, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37442430/3597276

Comment: Hi micheal, I thought of that but the only way to do that would be to add an inline style with width set dynamically. That is what I want to avoid.
I want the container and the caption to have the width of the image, if that's possible of course!
I tried using display: flex but couldn't get the caption to wrap when it reached the end of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with javascript. Here's a snippet using jQuery:

*Here's in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rickyruiz/kfcrtbLh/)*

```js
var imgSetByUser = $("img");

imgSetByUser.each(function(){

var thisImgWidth = $(this).width();
$(this).parent().css("max-width",thisImgWidth);

});
```

```css
.shrinkwrap { 
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
}

#version1 {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#version2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.caption {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.full {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Exact pixel length, no percentage --> 
<!-- Full width can be set as a class -->

<div class="shrinkwrap">

  <img id="version1" src="http://placehold.it/520x320" width="320px" alt="" /> <!-- % is relative to parent-->

  <div class="caption">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit ius ex admodum consequuntur, te dicunt epicurei invenire eum, te ius vocent eligendi. Sed unum persecuti te, tempor nostrud disputationi eos ad. ius ex admodum consequuntur, te dicunt epicurei inv!
  </div>

</div>


<br/><br/><br/>

<!-- Full width percentage and pixel length -->
<div class="shrinkwrap" style="width:500px">
    <img id="version2" src="http://placehold.it/520x320" alt="">
    <div class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius ex admodum consequuntur, te dicunt epicurei invenire eum, te ius vocent eligendi. Sed unum persecuti te, tempor nostrud disputationi eos ad. ius ex admodum consequuntur, te dicunt epicurei invenire eum, te ius vocent eligendi. Sed unum persecuti te, tempor nostrud disputationi eos ad.</div>
</div>
```