# How do i use floats for images while using <figure> so that <figcaption> still shows under image?

Tags: html, css

When i use `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` with floating images, e.g

```
<figure>
    <img id="one" src="xxx" />
    <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
</figure>
```

and in CSS:

```
#one {
    float: right;
}
```

the captions kind of stay on the page like regular text instead of appearing under respective `<img>`. How do I fix that? Does that have something to do with `display`?

Comment: Is it the `<img>` you want to float? Or the `<figure>`? It sounds like the `float` is doing exactly what it was intended to; though maybe not what you're expecting.

Comment: When I tried floating figures it did nothing at all. Possible that I managed to do it wrong though...

Comment: to clear figcaption from floatting image, ... use `clear:right;` or is it not the question ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37442616/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `clear` on *figcaption* element:

```
figcaption {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this at least makes them somehow.aligned. Raises more questions about how to make them captions fit under image, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

Floats can introduce unanticipated document flow issues (parent containers collapse around them; their floats can extend beyond their intended scope and push other elements around unexpectedly). If you are simply trying to stack the `<img>` over the `<figcaption>`, you might try changing the `<img>` element's `display` property to `block` in the CSS. You can read more on CSS floats [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

```css
figure {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  /* for illustration only */
  padding: 2px;
  /* for illustration only */
}
figure > img {
  border: 1px solid #f0f;
  /* for illustration only */
  display: block;
}
figcaption {
  border: 1px solid #0ff;
  /* for illustration only */
}
#one {
  /* float: right; */
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img id="one" src="xxx" />
  <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
</figure>
```