# How do I align a picture and its caption horizontally within 3 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

Using bootstrap I created three columns, each containing an image and a caption. Like so:

[image]

However, I want it to actually output the content like this:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
<!-- Section 6 -->
<div class="cssSection cssCenter">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>The Order</h2>
        <br>
        <p class="cssInformation">Labelled as a religious order, the Knights Templars established a set of rules by which their members would follow.</p>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img class="img-center img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x275">
                <br>
                    <p>The Templars swore to an oath of poverty, chastity, obedience and renounced the world.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img class="img-center img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x275">
                <br>
                    <p>The Templars lived within their own community, which meant sleeping in a common dorm, while also eating their meals in union. Lorem ipsum sont dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum sont dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum sont dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img class="img-center img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x275">
                <br>
                    <p>The Templars refrained from becoming drunk, gambling and swearing</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the related CSS code:

```
.cssSection {
    padding: 45px 0 30px;
}

.cssCenter {
    text-align: center;
}

.cssInformation {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

What can I adjust within the HTML and or CSS to make the p tags align horizontally, without affecting the images?

Comment: Try and add "display:flex; align-items:stretch;" to the .row class.

Comment: @ThomasByy thanks that did the trick

Comment: possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37442430/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no other css you might have added? I tried your code on jsfiddle (adding bootstrap) and it shows up fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here everything is fine in plunker. Please provide your whole html file to help us inspect your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well in bootstrap3.3.4.
Check your bootstrap version.