# Automatically assign width of <div> to contained <img> where width of image is not known

Tags: css

Not sure I worded the title optimally, but here's a simple explanation of my problem.

I have an HTML structure like so:

```
<div class="media-container" style="float: left">
  <img src="..." />
  <p class="caption">Here is a long caption that will extend beyond the width of the image.</p>
</div>
```

This is what it ends up looking like:

[image]

I want the caption text to line-break once it hits the width of the image so it instead looks like this:

[image]

I can get it the way I want by setting a fixed with on the container div, but I don't know that width ahead of time, so there's no way.

Are there any solutions to this problem I'm overlooking that are possible in pure CSS without involving JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried adding max-width to the div, e.g. max-width: 10em; or similar?

Comment: @PHClaus The problem is I don't know what value to set the width to, since it's dependent on the width of the image.

Comment: CSS has a calc function to do dynamic voodoo. Support is somewhat sparse but it may be what you are looking for. Have a look at the demo at www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

Comment: related: [Limiting caption to width of the image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37442430/3597276)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: table;`

```css
.media-container {
  display: table;
}

.caption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="media-container" style="float: left">
  <img width="100" src="https://d1ra4hr810e003.cloudfront.net/media/27FB7F0C-9885-42A6-9E0C19C35242B5AC/0/D968A2D0-35B8-41C6-A94A0C5C5FCA0725/F0E9E3EC-8F99-4ED8-A40DADEAF7A011A5/dbe669e9-40be-51c9-a9a0-001b0e022be7/thul-IMG_2100.jpg" />
  <p class="caption">Here is a long caption that will extend beyond the width of the image.</p>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4pL4wm9h/

Comment: This method seems to work the best so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the parent element:

```
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: min-content;
```

Details on `min-content` can be found [here](http://thenewcode.com/662/Design-From-the-Inside-Out-With-CSS-Min-Content)

[<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/O4kiJaQRRJgbfN6ap6xN/)

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    figure {
      float: left;
      width: -moz-min-content;
      width: -webkit-min-content;
      width: min-content;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by
    arches into stiff sections.</p>

  <p>The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought. It wasn't a dream.</p>


  <figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sbxyLKX.png">
    <figcaption>Here is a long caption that will extend beyond the width of the image.</figcaption>
  </figure>


  <p>His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had
    recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then
    turned to look out the window at the dull weather. Drops</p>
  <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so
    happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now. When,
    while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the
    trickling stream; and, as I lie close to the earth, a thousand unknown plants are noticed by me: when I hear the buzz of the little world among the stalks, and grow familiar with the countless indescribable forms of the insects and flies, then I feel
    the presence of the Almighty, who formed us in his own image, and the breath</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work in IE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width. I verified using browser stack as well. This seems like a great solution otherwise though, so thank you for posting this.