# Make width of text match headings width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a several divs enclosing a heading and text each. Some of the headings have a  manually set `<br />` and adjacent paragraph of text. I want the width of the text to be the same as the widest part of the heading.

How do I do this purely with CSS?

[image]

```css
.flex-text {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: start;
        color: #007990;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .flex-text p {
      color: #545641;
      text-align: justify;
    }
```

```html
    <div class='flex-text'>
      <h3>Supercool heading <br />done nicely</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Put it in a `div` and give that `div` a `max-width` then put the text in there.

Comment: Easiest would probably be to have both sit in the same container (`div` or whatever you fancy) and give that container a fixed width. Not really the dynamic solution you're looking for though. However, I'm not sure what you're trying to do is possible with just CSS.

Comment: I slightly changed the question and will try to create a stack snippet.

Comment: Here's the flex method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442430/limiting-caption-to-width-of-the-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using CSS tables, you just need to set `display: table` on parent element and set width to `1%` or something small and then use `white-space: nowrap` on heading.

This way heading will stay in one line and break line where you used `br` tag and text will have the same width as widest element or heading in this case.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1%;
}
h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br> consectetur.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci fugit minus, ad dicta ullam odio temporibus optio voluptatibus nisi, voluptatum molestias at. Molestiae maiores molestias ducimus praesentium vero, iusto laboriosam.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! I haven't touched `display: table` ever, so I didn't know this was possible. Would a similar approach also be possible with, say, `inline-block` or even flex?

Comment: This does actually work great. Browser support is also about 97%!

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested in the comments you can simply do this with a wrapper that surround both the title and the content and giving that wrapper a `max-width`

This max-width would be equal to whatever your header is. This should work in your case since the headers are set manually already.

```css
.flex-text {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: start;
        color: #007990;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .item {
      max-width: 153px;
    }
    
    .flex-text p {
      color: #545641;
      text-align: justify;
    }
```

```html
    <div class='flex-text'>
      <h3 class="item">Supercool heading <br />done nicely</h3>
      <p class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: This approach does not respect manual line-breaks via `<br />`. I added a Stack snippet to the original post.

Comment: Actually that's exactly why it does work, since you are manually controlling the break you are controlling the width and therefore you can set it. I'll update my answer with your stuff though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```css
.flex-text{
  max-width:270px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.flex-text h3{
  text-align:center;
  color: #545641;
  font-size:32px;
  line-height:100%;
}
.flex-text p{
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-text'>
  <h3>Supercool heading done nicely</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach does not work anymore when the `max-width` is set to a high value (e.g. 600px). The text just becomes too wide.